# Layer cannot access the methods used in the layer it references

Tags: c#, methods, 3-tier

I have 3 projects in the same solution, 3-tier architecture.

However I am failing to show my presentations in the presentation layer
I get the error CS0103, my thought is that the layer cannot access the methods used in the layer it references. If that's the case then how can I reference these methods or suggest an easy way to do this?

[image: User Image]

My presentation layer references the following code

```
using Data_Link;
using static Data_Link.Program;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Business_Logic
{
    public class Program 
    {


        List<Card> CrackableCards = GetCrackablePINS(AllCards);
        List<Card> ExpiredCards = GetExpiredCards(AllCards);
        List<Card> ExpiringCards = GetExpiringCards(AllCards);
        List<Card> HNWIs = GetHNWI(AllCards);

        public static List<Card> AllCards { get; private set; }

        /* List<Card> AllCards = new List<Card>();
         public int[] computeFrequency(List<LotteryEntry> historicalData)
         public static 

         */
        //Returns crackable pins
        private static List<Card> GetCrackablePINS(List<Card> cards)
        {
            List<Card> CrackableCards = GetCrackablePINS(AllCards);
            List<Card> results = new List<Card>();
            foreach (var card in cards)
            {
                if (IsCrackable(card.CardPIN))
                    results.Add(card);
            }
            return results;

        }
        //Returns expired cards
        private static List<Card> GetExpiredCards(List<Card> cards)
        {
            List<Card> results = new List<Card>();
            foreach (var card in cards)
            {
                if (HasExpired(card.ExpiryDate))
                    results.Add(card);
            }
            return results;
        }
        //Returns expiring cards
        private static List<Card> GetExpiringCards(List<Card> cards)
        {
            List<Card> results = new List<Card>();
            foreach (var card in cards)
            {
                if (IsExpiring(card.ExpiryDate))
                    results.Add(card);
            }
            return results;
        }
        //Returns HNWIs
        private static List<Card> GetHNWI(List<Card> cards)
        {
            List<Card> results = new List<Card>();
            foreach (var card in cards)
            {
                if (IsHNWI(card.CardLimit))
                    results.Add(card);
            }
            return results;
        }
        //Generates report in csv
         private void GenerateReport(List<Card> cardCriteria, string fileName)
        {
            string heading = "Card Type Code,Card Type Full Name,Issuing Bank,Card Number,Card Holder's Name,CVV/CVV2,Issue Date,Expiry Date,Billing Date,Card PIN,Credit Limit";
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, heading);
            foreach (var card in cardCriteria)
            {
                try
                {
                    string details = card.CardTypeCode + "," + card.CardTypeFullName + "," + card.IssusingBank + "," + card.CardNumber + "," + card.CardHolderName + "," + card.CVV + "," + card.IssueDate + "," + card.ExpiryDate + "," + card.BillingDate + "," + card.CardPIN + "," + card.CardLimit;
                    File.AppendAllText(fileName, details);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        //Checks if a card pin is crackable
        private static bool IsCrackable(string PIN)
        {
            if (PIN[0] == PIN[1] || PIN[1] == PIN[2] || PIN[2] == PIN[3])
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if ((int)PIN[0] == (int)PIN[1] - 1 && (int)PIN[1] == (int)PIN[2] - 1 && (int)PIN[2] == PIN[3] - 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        //Checks if the card has expired
        private static bool HasExpired(string date)
        {
            string[] dateString = date.Split('/');
            int month = int.Parse(dateString[0]);
            int year = int.Parse(dateString[1]);
            if (month <= 2 && year <= 2020)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        //Checks if the card is expiring
        private static bool IsExpiring(string date)
        {
            string[] dateString = date.Split('/');
            int month = int.Parse(dateString[0]);
            int year = int.Parse(dateString[1]);
            if (month == DateTime.Now.Month && year == DateTime.Now.Year)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        //Checks if a card is an HNWI
        private static bool IsHNWI(int HNWI)
        {
            const int limit = 149999;
            if (HNWI > limit)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All `private` Fields and Methods.

Comment: Pro tip: questions that have a title that is just general pleading will generally get closed here. Titles should always be indicative of a post's content.

Comment: @Jimi I tried changing the methods into public but still

Comment: You are using static methods, but the fields are per instance. Either declare your fields as `static` or instantiate a new instance of Program like this in the Main : `var myProgramInstance = new Program();`, and use `myProgramInstance.CrackableCards` for lists , etc..

Comment: as the Main method is static, it doesn't corresponds to an instance, so it doesn't "see" the lists you declared . But you can create an instance without issue. You need to get basic training on OOP (Object Oreinted Programmin) for the understanding.

Comment: @Pac0 I dont understand which fields and how

Comment: Ah, I haven't noticed it's not the same namespace. See Jasper Kent answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're using static `BusinessLogic.Program` will allow `public static` member of `BusinessLogic.Program` to be accessed.

However, your fields (`ExpiredCards` etc) are non-static and `private` (by default). Precede each of this with `public static`.

That said, it would probably be more maintainable to avoid static data. Instead, create and instance of `BusinessLogic.Program` inside `Main()`.

Comment: Which main? in the data, business or presentation layer?

Comment: You should only have one Main. Your business layer is (presumably) a DLL, so will not have a Main. Your presentation layer is (presumably) an EXE and has a Main. 

A DLL cannot be run directly, only accessed from and EXE (or another DLL). An EXE is run from the operating system, which calls Main as the entry point.

Comment: I have another main in the data layer. and removing this causes more errors

Comment: Depends how you remove it. I would simply rename it, because calling it Main will only cause confusion.